# Reactjs and inline styling, performance?

Tags: reactjs, performance, styles, material-ui

Currently I am learning React with material-ui and one thing wonders me:

```
<div data-reactroot="" class="wafe" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 1px 4px; border-radius: 2px; display: inline-block; min-width: 88px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); position: relative; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; width: 100%; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);"><div><div style="height: 36px; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; top: 0px;"><span style="position: relative; opacity: 1; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-user-select: none;">Guzik</span></div></div></button></div>
```

Does it has to apper like that? Is there any way to move this styling into another file/location, or it just has to be like this with React+material-ui?

Comment: you can do styling inline, create a style object in the component and use that, or put the styles in a separate css file and use the className attribute in the jsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material-UI uses inline styles to provide the most predictable behavior.
The components from mui have a lot of animations and them are controlled by javascript. This styles are generated from code.

Which kind of performance do you actually mean? Loading? Rendering?

1. Loading: JS, generated styles win, because if you are using proper build tools, you will get only the needed code, and the styles will are just a small part of it.
2. Rendering: Inline Styles win, because the renderer don't need to map the selectors to the styles, making the cascading to all the styles, it would also have to parse.

The benefits of inline Styles are huge. Benefits of CSS with JS are also very huge.

If you know some CSS frameworks like Bootstrap, you know, that a lot of the time you have to use wrappers. Like wrappers for containers, forms, panels, and so on. Because its hard, or even impossible to style a component with classes, if don't know the context. So the frameworks teach you to create wrappers, which are just stupid divs, but you need them to apply the styling you want to the inner parts.. Is it good? Is it simple? What about changing it? What about learning?

With inline styles its definitely simpler. If something is wrong, you just have to look into the component and change it there.

If you are using JS objects to describe your styles, you can share it, and name it. Naming and scoping brings you also a lot of positive side effects, you can create Components and use them where you want, without worrying about class names, because classnames are global.

If you use two different UI frameworks, they often uses the same names for buttons, `btn`, `button`, `panel` .. and all that stuff lives in your global document.. So its much more weirder, then use explicit styles for the explicit component.

You should check out this presentation, which is very good:

https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js

Comment: Thank you very much webdeb! I had no idea about this things. Untill this time i have found only Tips about separating CSS from everything, and that inline styling is pure evil! Surely your post helped me a lot with understanding :) BTW. Any hint, where could I find, newest information about JS world?

Comment: glad to help, well its definitely hard to be up to date all the time.. I would say the React Community is a good place, a lot of people are contributing to it. A lot of new concepts like Redux, which is independent form react, but works great with it. It also depends on your needs, and StackOverflow is also a good place, you'll learn a lot just by reading peoples questions and trying to solve, what you think is interesting ;)